# Azure Data Factory YAML deployment fails on overrideParameter key with space

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have deployed data factory instances via yaml pipelines and multiline overrideParameters successfully in the past but it seems that the Azure DevOps parser does not like keys that have spaces in them and fails with error 
`There was an error while overriding [my-parameter] parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)`.
The parameter name is automatically created via adf_publish branch so I cannot change it (I don't want to use custom templates if that is an option). Here is some sample setup and what I have tried.

**adf_publish arm parameter file**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "value": "my_adf"
        },
        "AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName": {
            "value": "my_aas_server"
        }
    }
}
```

**pipeline.yml**

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ variables.azureSubscription }}
    subscriptionId: ${{ variables.subscriptionId }}
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: ${{ variables.resourceGroupName }}
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf_branch/${{ variables.dataFactoryRepoPath }}/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf_branch/${{ variables.dataFactoryRepoPath }}/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: >-
      -factoryName "${{ variables.dataFactoryName }}"
      -AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName "${{ variables.aasShutdownServer }}"
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

I have tried the following variants on the parameter key (nothing worked)

- -AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName
- -"AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName"
- -'AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName'
- -["AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName"]
- -['AAS-Shutdown-Trigger_properties_AAS Shutdown_parameters_AASServerName']

If I remove the parameter in question, all works fine.

EDIT: Adding the adf resource definition of the trigger in question (as requested by @KamilNowinski

```
{
    "name": "AAS-Shutdown-Trigger",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "AAS Shutdown",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "AASServerName": "my-aas",
                    "ResourceGroupName": "my-rg",
                    "EtlPipelineName": "ETL Pipeline",
                    "KeyVaultName": "my-kv",
                    "OMSIdSecretName": "OMS-Workspace-ID",
                    "OMSKeySecretName": "OMS-Workspace-Key",
                    "AutomationAccountName": "my-atm",
                    "RunbookName": "aas-runbook"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 10,
                "startTime": "2020-10-07T13:27:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just looked at another (classic) pipeline with parameter keys having hyphens in them and the generated yaml does not put any special handling around those so presumably hyphens may not be the issue but the spaces.

Comment: I would take a look at the linked typescript in my answer - look at the `findLiteral` and `isName` methods. If `findLiteral` doesn't flag the result as having a special characeter because of `-`, then it's conceivable that `isName` would work.

Comment: I have never seen spaces in arm_template parameter file for params. That's looks weird. @Triamus, can you attach source code (JSON file) of the object which contains that parameter? Did you use custom parameters with the Resource Manager template?

Comment: @KamilNowinski added the json definition of the trigger in question.

Comment: Can't you just change the pipeline name removing space character? "AAS Shutdown" -> "AAS_Shutdown"

Comment: Well, yes. But these pipelines are partially created by business and we (IT) did not limit them as we assumed adf would be smart enough to handle these cases since it allows such pipeline names in the first place. But I guess we really have to enforce certain naming conventions to be able to deploy the adf.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` code for [PowershellParameters.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/e26f897bcac07201c9b490937c8318cabb50ad1e/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/operations/ParameterParser.ts), I don't think spaces in the parameter name can be handled.

The top `if` block of the `parse` method has the parser ending a symbol on a space (which is good, at least if you could handle quoting), but the `isName` method calls for there to be no "special" character in it (and quotes/brackets qualify as a special character by `findLiteral`).

I took the parser typescript and exercised it in a number of different ways, and none of them (including your variations) would allow that name to exist.

That doesn't mean there's no solution - what you *could* do is use an extension like [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to change that parameter name in both the template and the parameters file to something simpler, then use overrideParameters to alter THAT name.

Comment: Wow, you went deep. Then I don't understand how ADF is creating such parameter names and not replacing special characters with underscores. Seems like a bug-like behavior. I mean maybe we could have some function alter the automatically created adf_publish arm templates but that seems like a terrible hack imho.

Comment: Take a look at the "Replace Tokens" task in the Marketplace - you could insert it into your pipeline after the ADF publish, but before the ARM template deployment?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Still a terrible hack but potentially workable. I may try that out but also wait for MS to get back to my support ticket and see what they say.

Comment: There are days when Azure Pipelines feels like science, and days when it feels like a '57 Chevy with a leaking radiator that needs chewing gum. This is one of those days - the ADF team really thought it was a good idea to put a space in an ARM template parameter name? Really? Nobody consuming it downstream would encounter problems with that?

Comment: Haha. Ya I was thinking the same. And what is even stranger is that this does not seem to have come up before even for themselves? Hard to believe. But I didn't find anything on github or developer community. Actually, I think there is no github repo where I could post an issue as adf is not OSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer summarizing what we found so others have an easier time. As @WaitingForGuacamole has pointed out, it seems the ARM task source code cannot handle spaces in parameter keys irrespective of how one tries to quote it. So one would have to either introduce some function to replace spaces in parameter keys after ADF has published the ARM templates or one would have to pay attention not to have spaces in ADF pipeline names in the first place as pointed out by @KamilNowinski. I still believe it should not be that difficult for ADF to replace spaces (or any special character) with acceptable symbols before publishing. That still would leave the issue in case one would not use adf_publish ARM templates but rather edit the ADF json definitions directly.